# ¿Cómo mostrar en un select las todas las opciones que paso de php y recibo con ajax y jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, select

Necesito que cuando yo seleccione un *estado* se envie su *id* al archivo php, me busque todos los *municipios* de ese estado y me los muestre en el *select*. El código que tengo los busca pero **solo me muestra un municipio** y yo quiero que muestre todos los municipios no solo uno.

A continuación dejo el código que estoy usando:

**Código php**:

```
require_once 'Conexion.php';

$conexion = new Conexion();

$html = "";

$id_estado = $_POST["id_estado"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM municipios WHERE municipios.id_estado = '{$id_estado}'";
/*$sql = "SELECT * FROM municipios";*/

$datos = $conexion->consultaRetorno($sql);

/*if ($datos->num_rows > 0) {
while ($row = $datos->fetch_assoc()) {                
    $html = '<option value="'.$row['id_municipio'].'">'.$row['municipio'].'</option>';
}*/

$cursos = array();

while ($row = pg_fetch_array($datos)) {
    $id_municipio       =   $row["id_municipio"];
    $municipio          =   $row["municipio"];

    $cursos[] = array('id_municipio' => $id_municipio, 'municipio' => $municipio);
}

echo json_encode($cursos, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

El **jquery y ajax** con que lo recibo:

```
$("#estados").change(function () {
            $("#estados option:selected").each(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { 'id_estado': $(this).val()},
                    url: "<?php echo URL; ?>/Models/Consultas.php",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success : function(data) {
                        $.each(data, function(index){
                            console.log(data[index].municipio);
                            $("#municipios").html("<option>"+data.municipio[0]+"</option>")
                        })
                    }
                });

            });
        })
```

**html**:

```
<form action="">
<select name="estados" id="estados">
    <?php  while ($row = pg_fetch_array($datos)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['id_estado']; ?>"><?php echo $row['estado']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>

<div id="resultado"></div>

<select name="municipios" id="municipios">

</select>

<select name="parroquias" id="parroquias">

</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Porque el bucle se usa con la clave (index) y el valor (value), para iterar sobre cada elemento del objeto o del array:

```
$.each(data, function(index, value){
    console.log(value.municipio);
    html("<option>" + value.municipio[0] + "</option>");
});
```

Te paso la documentación por si la quieres revisar:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 1):

Primero, si la respuesta es un arreglo debes saber que tienes que recorrerlo y dar el `value` para que cuando vayas a utilizar el valor, llegue.

```
$.each(data, function(index){
      console.log(data[index].municipio);
      $("#municipios").append("<option value='"+data.municipio[0].id_municipio+"'>"+data.municipio[0].municipio+"</option>");
})
```

De esta forma, cuando el usuario seleccione el nombre del municipio y quiera guardar los datos, el valor seleccionado tendra el valor de la id.